# Highcharts - Provide URL's for series data to open clickable link

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to add a url to each of my data points inside my series that when clicked user is redirected to that page. For example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awasM/) .

```
series:[{data: [ [123.12,'http://xyz.com'],[332.32,'http://zzs.com'] ] }]
```

I was able to get the points to be clickable, but how I actually get them to find the point I am clicking on and which url to use I can't figure out. I can obviously hack it by using an alternative array that stores the links... but I would like to use chart as it's meant.

**Now that it has been solved for future reference to be able to add links to your points here is the code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/awasM/2/

Comment: The link no longer works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use structure:

```
 data:[{
   y:10,
   ownURL:'http://www.google.com'
 },{
   y:11,
   ownURL:'http://www.google2.com'
 },{
   y:5,
   ownURL:'http://www.google3.com'
 }]
```

and then you have ability to "get" this value by

```
this.point.options.ownURL
```

Comment: Thank you, i've implemented the solution and it works like a charm. I wasn't aware of the ability to structure your data. And for those who are interested in how I pulled it off here is a real example (the "this" doesn't really work with my method). http://jsfiddle.net/awasM/2/

Comment: You should catch point click event inside series. So please take look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/awasM/5/

Comment: Fiddle above seems to be missing, so here's one demonstrating the answer:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3pxosb4x/

Answer (score 11):

Here's one way to do this (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awasM/1/)):

```
                       series: [{
                            name: 'Batch',
                            URLs: ['www.google.com', null, null, 'www.yahoo.com', null, null, 'www.cnn.com', null, null, 'www.minecraft.net'], // pass in array of URLs
                            data: [4375.48, 113599.39, 1278, 83950.12, 6579.65, 94582, 1285.65, 48700.39, 500, 62917.27],
                            color:'#b8ecce',
                            point: {
                                events: {
                                    click: function() {
                                        var someURL = this.series.userOptions.URLs[this.x]; // onclick get the x index and use it to find the URL
                                        if (someURL)
                                            window.open('http://'+someURL);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                       }],
```

Comment: Thanks for the working code, but I like Sebastians way a little better as it resembles what I will be passing from backend.

Comment: Could you repost the fiddle as that's exactly what I need please?