# Highcharts Line Chart - Hyperlink on a data point

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am working on an application to create Line Chart using the Highcharts API. This application involves plotting a Date vs. Time Line Chart.

I need to have dynamic hyperlinks, for all or some of the data points.

The data for this chart is being retrieved from a database table and converted into JSON. This JSON is then being parsed by JavaScript and converted into data array that can be consumed by the Highcharts API. There is some data manipulation being done in the JavaScript while converting the data from JSON to data array.

The Highcharts API accepts the input in data array format that comprises of [x, y] combinations.

As I need to have a dynamic hyperlink for all or some of the data points, I have created another array that comprises of the hyperlinks.

I am unable to retrieve the hyperlink URL from the array on the fly as a particular hyperlink is clicked by the user.

I tried using it they was it has been used in this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/awasM/1/

A snippet of my code is given below:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Release',
        data: dataArray,
        URLs: urlArray,
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    var someURL = this.series.userOptions.URLs[this.x];
                    if (someURL != "undefined")
                        window.open(someURL);
                }
            }
        }
    }]
```

However, as in my case date (in Unix/Epoch time format) is on x-axis (and time on y-axis), so using the x-axis value does not work.

Comment: Example provided by you looks completely different from the one you explained

Comment: I advice to check the similar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176390/highcharts-provide-urls-for-series-data-to-open-clickable-link

Answer (score 0):

i hope you could match this code to fix something.

```
  point: {
             events: {
                      click: function() {
                        var pointObject = this;
                        var pointindex = pointObject.x;
                        var pointdata = pointObject.y;
                        var getIndexOfURL = this.series.userOptions.URLs[pointindex];
                        var getIndexOfData = this.series.userOptions.data[pointindex];   
                        if (getIndexOfURL){
                           window.open('http://'+getIndexOfURL);
                        }

                      }
             }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, TimeGuard. However, limitation in my code is that the x-axis values are time in Unix/Epoch format (in milliseconds), like 1394089005000; this is to fetch the date. Fetching this.x will return this value and not the index of the point clicked. Due to this limitation, I am unable to retrieve the index of the point that the user has clicked.

Comment: You could try this.series.index for the index number. I use the browser's JS debugger to inspect the "this" parameter properties after breakpointing at the relevant line.