# Highcharts - URL's for series data to open clickable link

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need a solution to add unique URL's to my series.

This former [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176390/highcharts-provide-urls-for-series-data-to-open-clickable-link?lq=1), unfortunately does not work anymore.

```
 series: [{
            name: 'batch',
            visible: false,
             marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
              symbol: 'square'
            },          
            data:[56.5,50.1,49.4,50.8,51.8,50.4,51.1,50],
            color: 'darkred',
            }, {
```

Something like this?

```
series:[{data: [ [123.12,'http://goole.com'],[332.32,'http://zzs.com'] ] }]
```

Comment: Are you sure that answers from the topic you gave aren't working? You can find this example. It should work in your case http://jsfiddle.net/36m90mkw/ you need to remove 'xxx' letters from window.locxxxation.href to make it works.

Comment: The answer, as given in the post you linked to, seems to work just fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/156/

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzBlachliński and jibriggs. Thank you for the quick response. I have added the "window.open(this.options.ownURL)" part to my plotoptions, which makes the series to links. But I cannot get it to work properly since I don't have any data for the X-axis. How do I insert it correctly? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/158/)

Comment: You can use keys parameter if you want to have your data in format of [123.12,'link']. Here you can see an example how it can work http://jsfiddle.net/36m90mkw/1/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - what is "data for the x axis" ? Can you update the fiddle I posted with appropriate data to match your issue? In my example, I am not sending an x value; in @GrzegorzBlachliński 's example, he is mapping the keys, and you can just remove the 'x' key if you're not sending an x value. So either way, you don't need an explicit x value in your data to make this work.

Comment: @jlbriggs I am sorry for the confusion. I ment 'data for the y axis. Could you help me with an example with the Line Chart instead of the column?

Comment: My data input looks like [jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/158/](http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/158/)
@GrzegorzBlachliński - I have updated your example [jsfiddle.net/36m90mkw/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/36m90mkw/2/). How do I type more data in, if every point needs to be a link?

Comment: If every point should be different link, please take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/36m90mkw/4/ As you can see instead of using simple one data value, you can use an array [y, link] and it should work in your case.

Comment: I have more than 500 different points on each series, so I need to find a solution without having to write the URL on each line. @GrzegorzBlachliński

Comment: So If I understand you correctly you want to have one link for each series, not one link for each point? Here you can see an example http://jsfiddle.net/36m90mkw/5/

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I needed. Thank you for the help @GrzegorzBlachliński !